# ¿Como validar que dato(filas) cargar a un BD desde una tabla en excel?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel, webforms

**Estoy que uso C# en asp.net web y sql server 2014.** 
Tengo un cuadro de excel de 3 columnas y 5 filas, al que quiero cargar a la BD siempre y cuando cumplan los requisitos (me refiero a las filas) 
Por ejemplo: Si de 5 filas, en la tercera fila de la columna "costo" puso la palabra "cien" o cualquier otra, solo cargar a la BD la fila 1, 2, 4 y 5.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mandar un mensaje de que solo se cargo 4 filas de 5

Comment: es una desarrollo web, como trabajas con el excel? que libreria usas para leerlo

Answer (score 0):

Si usas `ado.net` para acceder a los datos del excel podrias volcar esto a un datatable y luego procesarlo

[Lectura/Escritura de archivos Excel con ADO.NET](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/484/LecturaEscritura-de-archivos-Excel-con-ADONET.aspx)

algo como ser

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";"
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();

    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Datos$]"; //aqui pondrias el nombre de la solapa
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

}
```

teniendo el datatable luego podrias iterar cada row o aplicar linq

```
foreach(var row in dt.Rows){

    int costo = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(row["Costo"].ToString(), out costo)){

       //si ingresa aqui pudo convertir el valor a numerico

    }

}
```